# After execution of ODataModel submitChanges function, some data is missing

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I would like to ask why after execution of the submitChanges, some of the data did not create?

```js
aData.forEach(function (oData) {
    oData.value1 = "some value"; // Set some values
    oModel.createEntry("/TreeData", {
        properties: oData
    });
});

oModel.submitChanges({
    success: function (oData, sResponse) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Before execution of submitChanges, I have check for the pendingChanges, which contain 301 lines to be create.

But after the execution, only 297 lines created, 4 lines missing.

I've check using attachRequestCompleted and sResponse (from success of submitChanges), it show 301 lines are "Created".

I'm also check for each of the keys, no duplicate is found.

I tried for 30 lines and 100 lines as well, no problem at all.

Comment: Is this also reproducible with a mockserver? Then it could be a bug. Try [creating an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new) with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe one of the maintainers can spot the issue.